# What species of flying insect is this? Resembles a fly with the wings of a dragonfly

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Locus: Vienna, Austria

Local Time : 12:24 today, 6th of January

Size: length approximately a large thumb. Width much smaller (pic).

Behaviour: possibly attracted by honey in my medicine, along with flies.

[image]

Comment: Definitely in Syrphidae.

Comment: Might be Episyrphus. In any case, the common name for the family is "Hoverfly".

Comment: @KarlKjer After consulting Wikipedia, I tend to agree. Furthermore, I am amazed to see that this kind of eyes apparently makes it a female! https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episyrphus_balteatus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insect ID from photos is difficult, but this is definitely in Syrphidae. The alternating thick and thin stripes on the abdomen resemble very much those in a picture I found here: https://alchetron.com/Episyrphus-balteatus
I would say that it is likely in the genus, *Episyrphus*, which is present in Austria.

Comment: Syrphidae are usually easily identified from photo. This is without a doubt *E. balteatus*. There is no other species that resembles it in Europe.

Comment: Could you provide further support using [Comstock-Needham system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comstock%E2%80%93Needham_system) out of curiosity?